# Zend framework: Concurrent ajax calls cause user to be logged out

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, authentication, concurrency

In my Zend application I have several Ajax actions to pull in forms or json arrays of data.

When two Ajax actions occur concurrently (from the same logged in session) one of them returns the login screen. Furthermore on occasion (but not on every occurrence) this also results in the user being logged out upon requesting another page from the application. Whilst debugging I've found that in the following code (in our LoginRequired helper) the if clause is run. This clause is not run under normal operation of the site unless the user is actually logged out.

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
if(!$auth->hasIdentity()){
   ...
}
```

My question is: **"Why do concurrent Ajax calls cause this behaviour and what can I do about it?"**

I'd like a solution which does not involve sacrificing the asynchronous nature of the ajax requests nor the security of the system.

Thank you.

Comment: We has a situation once when browser didn't provide php session identificator along with the request. We had to add it to request manually. Check with firebug if this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a classic race condition. See this great article: http://www.chipmunkninja.com/Troubles-with-Asynchronous-Ajax-Requests-g@

Solutions that come to mind include closing sessions sooner or rewriting [session_set_save_handler()](http://www.sitepoint.com/race-conditions-ajax-and-sessions/)

Comment: I've tried closing sessions immediately after modification. This does not have any effect. I can't rewrite session_set_save_handler in this environment.

Comment: What is preventing you from writing your own session handler?

Comment: Session handling is part of the ZEND framework not part of the application code. So I'd be introducing an upgrading problem. Wouldn't I?

Comment: Not at all.  ZF is designed to be extensible.  Just look at [Zend_Session_SaveHandler_Interface](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.9/Zend_Session/SaveHandler/Zend_Session_SaveHandler_Interface.html)... "method provides an object-oriented wrapper for » session_set_save_handler()."